# Installing sockets.io using npm through our Vagrant box

Tags: sockets, npm, vagrant, package-managers

I am running the following command in my Vagrant box (its running Unix)

```
sudo npm install -g socket.io
```

I get the following response after a number of seconds..

```
> ws@0.4.31 install /usr/lib/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
```

Can anyone explain this... and what should I do next?

P.S When I run sudo npm -list it doesn't seem to have installed socket.io

Comment: Had almost the same issue, what i did is go to pupphpet and reconfigure and run vagrant provision. I know is not the perfect workaround but no other choices

Answer (score 0):

Try follow one of these links maybe you could get things right

https://blog.liip.ch/archive/2012/07/25/vagrant-and-node-js-quick-tip.html

https://serverfault.com/questions/345341/cant-create-symlinks-in-virtualbox-shared-folders

Also try npm install --no-bin-links